# It's possible to add new source to video?

Tags: javascript, html, video

This is possible?

Im working on video streaming. it's possible to add new source when someone input on a form? send to video source?

```
<!-- CSS  -->
 <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.2.3/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>


<!-- HTML -->
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls="" height="400" id="hls-example" width="700" preload="none">
<source src="CHANGE IF SOMEONE INPUT IN URL FORM" type="application/x-mpegURL"></source>
</video>


<!-- JS code -->
<!-- If you'd like to support IE8 (for Video.js versions prior to v7) -->
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/ie8-version/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-contrib-hls/5.14.1/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.2.3/video.js"></script>

<script>
var player = videojs('hls-example');
player.play();
</script>
```

Im not good in js. can someone help me? when user try to put something in " url form " then the page will refresh and save the new "URL"

Thank you!

Comment: please provide examples of sources that you want to use for video and what is `"url form"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send GET parameters by form:

```
<input name="vname">
```

You can obtain GET request parameters like this:

```
var vname = new URL(window.location.href).searchParams.get('vname');
```

And attach to source src:

```
document.querySelector("source").src = vname;
```

And Use `localStorage` to store filename:

```html
<!-- CSS  -->
 <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.2.3/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>


<!-- HTML -->
<form>
<input name='vname' placeholder="Enter filename">
<input type='submit'>
</form>
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls="" height="400" id="hls-example" width="700" preload="none">
<source src="" type="application/x-mpegURL"></source>
</video>


<!-- JS code -->
<!-- If you'd like to support IE8 (for Video.js versions prior to v7) -->
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/ie8-version/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-contrib-hls/5.14.1/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.2.3/video.js"></script>

<script>
var vname = new URL(window.location.href).searchParams.get('vname');
if(vname != null){localStorage.setItem("vname",vname);}
document.querySelector("video source").src = localStorage.getItem("vname") == "" ? vname : localStorage.getItem("vname");
var player = videojs('hls-example');
player.play();
//alert(document.querySelector("video source").src);
</script>
```

*Note that write video name with extension in input field*